# Using two different DB users on one WP install

Tags: database, security

I'm curious as to whether the following is possible as there are concerns that the WP site in question may be hacked via the front end & through a plugin..

1. We want to have the front-end connect via a Read-Only DB user
2. We want the admin area to have Read/Write access but have this URL protected by the server firewall rule that only allows internal traffic

I'm open to other suggestions

Comment: so basically if the url contains /wp-admin/ then it should connect to different DB ( for admin purpose ) and else it should connect to other DB ( for read purpose ) . If this is the case, then yes it is possible

Comment: Yes, do you have a tutorial a plugin or reference as to how to implement this?

Comment: I had setup a same website .

Please check the answer section.

Comment: This will cause problems if your theme or plugins try to create transients to cache things. You'll also need to make exceptions for the Admin AJAX endpoint which is used on the frontend

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell the site has minimal plugins and a custom theme but out of interest sake, are you saying that the front end may need to write to the database in the normal course of users simply viewing content? There is no functionality other than displaying posts - there isn't even a form.

Comment: @Daniel yes, transients are stored in the database and used to cache expensive things. For example, on my own site, I cache the menus and widgets so they load instantly in a transient. RSS feed requests get cached too. There's also WP Cron, which is not in WP Admin, scheduled posts, etc may not work as a result as there's no way to update them. You also have the REST API, which will be unable to write anything even in WP Admin as it sits at `/wp-json`.

Comment: In all honesty, you'd get much better security from making your file system read only outside of the uploads folder, using HTTPS, forcing logins to use 2FA, and making sure all your content is escaped

Comment: @TomJNowell ok, I see your point. I hadn't considered the impact of this on WP Cron as this will be used for a plugin I'm writing. As for the other suggestions, Read-Only and SSL are being implemented next week and the IT department will be implementing firewall rules to restrict access to the /wp-admin URL to internal traffic only. I've also added Wordfence premium as another precaution. Thanks for the valuable input!

Comment: You'll need exemptions for certain files under wp-admin, specifically wp-admin-ajax, as it's used both on the frontend and the backend. Also, `xmlrpc.php` will need write access for Jetpack to work, as will `/wp-json` for some plugins and in the future Core itself will use it more extensively

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have setup WP instance with 2 different database, one for read only and other for admin purpose.

But once the admin make the changes, then the ADMIN-DB should be copied and added to SLAVE-DB server.

```
// check if url contains wp-login or wp-admin and then create DB configuration for Master DB else Slave DB.
$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ( false !== strpos( $url, 'wp-admin' ) || false !== strpos( $url, 'wp-login' ) ) {
    define( 'DB_NAME', 'SLAVE_DB_NAME' );
    define( 'DB_USER', 'SLAVE_DB_USER' );
    define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'SLAVE_DB_PASSWORD' );
    define( 'DB_HOST', 'SLAVE_DB_HOST' );
} else {
    define( 'DB_NAME', 'MASTER_DB_NAME' );
    define( 'DB_USER', 'MASTER_DB_USER' );
    define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'MASTER_DB_PASSWORD' );
    define( 'DB_HOST', 'MASTER_DB_HOST' );

}
```

Comment: Question was cool, so my answer helped you out :)

Comment: Definitely, I realised after I asked it that I can use one DB and have the different users in the configs. Did you put this code in the wp-config?

Comment: Yes, in wp-config.php file .

Comment: Is it possible that your `if` statement has the DB's in the wrong order? When I tried this on my dev site it worked but I couldn't log in - I assumed this was somehow related to the user and how WP stores sessions in the DB so I altered it to `if ( strpos( $url, 'wp-admin' ) || strpos( $url, 'wp-login' ) ) {` and switched the DB's around which now works

Comment: oops, yes the order is incorrect. thanks for correcting it